# Convert RepeatedField to List

Tags: .net, protocol-buffers, grpc, protobuf-net, protobuf-csharp-port

.Net

My protobuf file:

```
message Result{
    repeated ListOfStrings lists = 1;
}

message ListOfStrings {
    repeated string strings = 1;
}
```

And I have a class with this property:

```
public List<List<string>> ListOfLists { get; set; }
```

Protobuf compiler generates `RepeatedField` collection and when I'm trying to pass this collection to `ListOfLists.AddRange()` I get this error:

`cannot convert from 'Google.ProtobufCollections.RepeatedField<gRPC.ListOfStrings>' to 'System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>`

**How to deal with it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `List<List<string>>` is not the same as a list of things that *have* strings. You will probably need:

```cs
foreach (var list in outerList) {
    var inner = new ListOfStrings();
    inner.Strings.AddRange(list);
    obj.Lists.Add(inner);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the `CopyTo` method, [doc](https://developers.google.cn/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/collections/repeated-field-t-#class_google_1_1_protobuf_1_1_collections_1_1_repeated_field_3_01_t_01_4_1a6f8d653573cecec20fcef6a9695c0ec4)

Sample Pseudocode code:

```
 Result result = ...
 foreach(var list in result.list)
 {
    string[] arr = new string[list.Count];
    list.CopyTo(arr,0);
    ListOfLists.Add(arr.ToList());
 }
```